# My `Buttonhandler` always causes this error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Aight, so I have an ion-picker and I gave it a done-button which reads the selected value and saves it in an array. The entire thing works with no problem, but it's always causing this error to be displayed when I compile it:

```
"error TS2322: Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 
'(value: any) => boolean | void'.
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void'.
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'."
```

It's not a real problem since the error only shows up when I compile it and doesn't do any real damage, but still, I would like for it to be solved.

I tried playing around with it a lot to solve the problem, but nothing made the error go away without also destroying the functionality of the handler. (shown below)

```
{
     text: 'Done',
     role: 'confirm',
     handler: async () => {
         const vari = await this.picker.getColumn(this.pickervalues[id].name);
         this.selectedvalue = vari.options[vari.selectedIndex].text;
         this.selected[id] = this.selectedvalue;
     }
}
```

Anyone an idea on how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *then* instead of async/awiat:

```
{
  text: 'Done',
  role: 'confirm',
  handler: () => {
    this.picker.getColumn(this.pickervalues[id].name).then(() => {
      this.selectedvalue = vari.options[vari.selectedIndex].text;
      this.selected[id] = this.selectedvalue;
    });
  }
}
```

See this [Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12675)
 for additional reference.